# django model post_save send email if allowed from user profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to send email to user after object is saved. But can't get the user profile to find is it allowed or not, before sending.

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
    notifications = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...

class Follow(models.Model):
    who = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='he_follow')
    whom = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='him_follow')

    ...

    def send_notification(sender, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            obj = kwargs['instance']
            check_it = obj.whom.get_profile().notifications
            if check_it == True:
                #rest code for sending emails works
            else:
                pass

    post_save.connect(send_notification)
```

This return me error `'LogEntry' object has no attribute 'whom'`  so I was think it is because there is no sender in post_save. But after I change the post_save line to `

```
    post_save.connect(send_notification, sender=Follow)
```

django crashes with error `NameError: name 'Follow' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is the alignment of your function. You put it under Follow model, it must be outside the model.

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    who = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='he_follow')
    whom = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='him_follow')

    ...

//align with Follow model don't put it inside

def send_notification(sender, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        obj = kwargs['instance']
        check_it = obj.whom.get_profile().notifications
        if check_it == True:
            #rest code for sending emails works
        else:
            pass

post_save.connect(send_notification, sender=Follow)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the parameters you are requiring/sending to `send_notification`.

Arguments sent with post_save signal ([post_save in Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save)):

- sender: The model class.
- **instance**: The actual instance being saved.
- created: A boolean; True if a new record was created.
- raw: A boolean; True if the model is saved exactly as presented (i.e. when loading a fixture). One should not query/modify other records in the database as the database might not be in a consistent state yet.
- using: The database alias being used.

Your `send_notification` method should look something like this in your `signals.py` file:

```
from yourproject.yourapp.models import Follow

... 

def send_notification(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        check_it = kwargs['instance'].whom.get_profile().notifications
        if check_it == True:
            #rest code for sending emails works
        else:
            pass

post_save.connect(send_notification, sender=Follow)
```

Comment: thank you Daniel but I receive the same error ` 'LogEntry' object has no attribute 'whom' `

Comment: Is your `post_save.connect(send_notification, sender=Follow)` line within your `models.py` file? If it's somewhere else like `signals.py` then it sounds like you are just not importing the `Follow` class model in `signals.py`.

Comment: yes it is including intendation above but when I add ` sender=Follow ` django crashes as  I explain above.

Comment: thank you Daniel alignment is the key but you help me a lot up for you thanks again.